# Dynamic variable python in a loop

Tags: python, loops, variables, dynamic

I was looking through many posts here for a solution but maybe I was searching for the wrong phrase. I'm new to python, my code problem is the following:

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
for line in open('fcts.txt'):
   yahoo = Share('YHOO')
   print (yahoo +'.' + line)
```

it should basically do the following but for every function inside `fcts.txt`:

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
yahoo = Share('YHOO')
print (yahoo.get_open())
```

while `fcts.txt` contains different functions like

```
get_open()
get_change()
...
```

Thank you,
Stefan

Comment: I can't understand your question. What is in fcts.txt? Python functions?

Comment: Names of Python methods of a `Share` instance.

Comment: Why do you have sort of weird half-code in your txt file…? Doesn't seem very sane.

Comment: thanks to Alfe for the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access methods by name like this:

```
from yahoo_finance import Share

with open('fcts.txt') as methodsFile:
  for methodName in methodsFile:
    yahoo = Share('YHOO')
    method = getattr(yahoo, methodName.strip())
    print (method())
```

But it looks rather crude to me.

Comment: Your `fcts.txt` should contain lines like `get_open` and `get_change` without the parentheses, though.  If you have parentheses in the file, use `methodName.strip('() \n')` instead.

Comment: Thank you Alfe for the quick solution. Works perfect and I altered the fcts.txt as you mentioned.

Comment: :)  Welcome to StackOverflow!  If you think an answer solved the issue from the question, feel free to accept it (click the ckeckmark left of the answer).